# Prevent InputMethodService changing the Number keyboard to Alpha when the user touches on a webview for the second time

Tags: android, webview, focus, touch, android-input-method

I am having a problem with the Android keyboard getting changed from number type to the default Alpha when the user clicks again. After reading several posts about not being able to change the default type of the keyboard from alpha to numeric on a webview I have followed the below procedure. I have created a hidden EditText control and changed the keyboard type from that control and it worked fine, now I get the Numeric SIP and all the key presses are dispatched to the webview correctly. But the problem is if the user touches again on the webview the keyboard type is changed from numeric to alpha by the InputMethodService and I don’t receive any callback for this event.

```
V/InputMethodService( 1764): CALL: onStartInput
```

I can think of the below possible solutions but none seem to work.

1.Is there a way to change the default keyboard type through InputMethodManager on a webview?

2.If a Number keyboard is already shown then can we prevent the InputMethodManager to change to the default alpha keyboard when the user touches again?

3.Is there a way to override or receive a callback for onStartInput() method of the InputMethodService?

```
InputMethodManager imm;
if (mWebEditText == null)
{
    mWebEditText = new WebEditText(Common.mainActivity.getApplicationContext(),view.getView());
}

mWebEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
webEditTextPanel.addView(mWebEditText, lp);

mWebEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
mWebEditText.requestFocus();
imm.showSoftInput(mWebEditText, 0);
```

WebEditText class:

```
public class WebEditText extends EditText
{
//Pointer to the web view to dispatch the keys
View mWebView;

public WebEditText(Context context, View view)
{
    super(context);     
    mWebView = view;        
}   

/**
 * Override the dispatch key event to send the key events to the web view
 * from the invisible Edit Text control
 */
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
{       
    mWebView.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);       
}
```

Comment: Can you share the content of the webview too?

Comment: Hi..any update on problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is from your HTML code which you are showing in the webview. change the input type of the EditText(textbox) to number.

```
 <input type="number" placeholder="Text box lable" id="Text box id" required value="defautvalue" />
```

Edit :

```
EditText e = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            e.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            appView.addView(e);
```

can you add the edittext in the way i have done. it works fine for me in my applicaiton

Comment: the EditText(textbox) is a hidden field and not visible to the HTML code. I create this EditText when the user clicks on any input control (type=number) in the webview.

Comment: so you are creating the edittext from code and adding that in the webview?

Comment: Change the ans, please check

Comment: Sorry, I'm also doing the same, right? I cant find the difference between these two, please can you elaborate on what I'm doing it different. I have updated my question with the WebEditText class definition.

Comment: You are making the wrapper around the original EditText and hence when you extend that with some other class it has it's own memory stack to run. so when user touches the editbox once it executes the code for showing it as numberic pad but after that it treat that as normal webview and hence problem starts.

Comment: Thank you Drax for the information. I tried using direct EdiTtext class rather than my class but still I see the same behaviour. Please note that I am placing the EdiTtext at -200, -200 position so that its not visible to the user even if some CSS stylings are applied.

Comment: can you put send me your project code if possible? i need to see it in the deep

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25359/discussion-between-harish-and-drax)